# How to pass two values as State in Spark Streaming?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, streaming

I tried to implement a Spark Streaming application that reads streaming data from Kafka. The streaming data are (key, value) pairs in the form of "String,int", and I want to calculate the average value of each key. 
The data is in form as below:

```
x,20
y,10
z,3
...
```

I want to measure the average value for each key in a stateful manner. Therefore, I intend to save the sum of value and how many times its corresponding key appears into the `State` in the mapping function.

```
 def mappingFunc(key: String, value: Option[Double], state: State[Double], count: State[Int]): (String, Double) = {
        val sum = value.getOrElse(0.0) + state.getOption.getOrElse(0.0)
        val cnt = count.getOption.getOrElse(1) + 1
        state.update(sum)
        count.update(cnt)
        val output = (key, sum/cnt)
        output
    }
```

It reminds me there's an error:

```
[error] /Users/Rabbit/Desktop/KTH_Second_Year/Periods/P1/Data-intensive_Computing/Lab_Assignment/lab3/src/sparkstreaming/KafkaSpark.scala:78: wrong number of type parameters for overloaded method value function with alternatives:
[error]   [KeyType, ValueType, StateType, MappedType](mappingFunction: org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function3[KeyType,org.apache.spark.api.java.Optional[ValueType],org.apache.spark.streaming.State[StateType],MappedType])org.apache.spark.streaming.StateSpec[KeyType,ValueType,StateType,MappedType] <and>
[error]   [KeyType, ValueType, StateType, MappedType](mappingFunction: org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function4[org.apache.spark.streaming.Time,KeyType,org.apache.spark.api.java.Optional[ValueType],org.apache.spark.streaming.State[StateType],org.apache.spark.api.java.Optional[MappedType]])org.apache.spark.streaming.StateSpec[KeyType,ValueType,StateType,MappedType] <and>
[error]   [KeyType, ValueType, StateType, MappedType](mappingFunction: (KeyType, Option[ValueType], org.apache.spark.streaming.State[StateType]) => MappedType)org.apache.spark.streaming.StateSpec[KeyType,ValueType,StateType,MappedType] <and>
[error]   [KeyType, ValueType, StateType, MappedType](mappingFunction: (org.apache.spark.streaming.Time, KeyType, Option[ValueType], org.apache.spark.streaming.State[StateType]) => Option[MappedType])org.apache.spark.streaming.StateSpec[KeyType,ValueType,StateType,MappedType]
```

How can I pass the sum of value and the count at the same time in Spark Streaming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to combine the sum and the count as tuple `(Double, Int)` which is stored in the state. The following snippet should do the trick:

```
def mappingFunc(key: String, value: Option[Double], state: State[(Double, Int)]): (String, Double) = {
    val (sum, cnt) = state.getOption.getOrElse((0.0, 0))
    val newSum = value.getOrElse(0.0) + sum
    val newCnt = cnt + 1
    state.update((newSum, newCnt))
    (key, newSum/newCnt)
}
```